# JQuery notifications on click not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using Javascript to update HTML content of a list of network devices. I'm using Notify library:
http://getuikit.com/docs/notify.html
A network device can be online (up and running) and after few seconds go Offline.
When I load my web page and Device is already Offline when I click on it I can display the notification alert. But when my web page is open/active and device changes from Online to Offline, no alert is displayed when I click on it.

Page loaded HTML (Works)

```
<div data-uk-observe id=<?php echo $device_list['serialnumber'];?> show="1" data-toggle="notify" data-message="System is offline" data-options="{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;danger&quot;, &quot;pos&quot;:&quot;top-right&quot;}">
<a href="#" ><?php echo $device_list['serialnumber']?></a>
</div>
```

This is the JS used to change HTML dynamically in the device dashboard (Not working).

```
document.getElementById(serialNumber).setAttribute("show", "1");
document.getElementById(serialNumber).setAttribute("data-toggle", "notify");
document.getElementById(serialNumber).setAttribute("data-message", "System is offline");
document.getElementById(serialNumber).setAttribute("data-options", "{\"status\":\"danger\", \"pos\":\"top-right\"}");

// Remove A tag
$('#' + serialNumber).find('a').remove();
// Add new A HREF
$('#' + serialNumber).append('<a href="javascript:void(0);">' + serialNumber + '</a>');
```

When I compared the HTML using Firebug it's identical:

Web page loaded

```
<div data-uk-observe="" id="99238944-13231" show="1" data-toggle="notify" data-message="System is offline" data-options="{"status":"danger", "pos":"top-right"}">
<a href="javascript:void(0);">99238944-13231</a>
</div>
```

After injecting HTML

```
<div data-uk-observe="" id="99238944-13232" show="1" data-toggle="notify" data-message="System is offline" data-options="{"status":"danger", "pos":"top-right"}">
<a href="javascript:void(0);">99238944-13232</a>
</div>
```

in my JQuery handling element click is never invoked after injecting HTML.

```
(function($, window, document){
  'use strict';

  var Selector = '[data-toggle="notify"]',
      autoloadSelector = '[data-onload]',
      doc = $(document);

  $(function() {

    $(Selector).each(function(){

      var $this  = $(this),
          onload = $this.data('onload');

      if(onload !== undefined) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          notifyNow($this);
        }, 800);
      }

      $this.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('Click!');
        e.preventDefault();
        notifyNow($this);
      });

    });

  });

  function notifyNow($element) {
      var message = $element.data('message'),
          options = $element.data('options');

      if(!message)
        $.error('Notify: No message specified');

      $.notify(message, options || {});
  }

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

I tried data-uk-observe as documentation, but stuck why is not responding.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling the API as documented here: http://getuikit.com/docs/notify.html . You're manipulating the DOM instead. Are you expecting the library to respond to your DOM changes?

Comment: Hi Jacob, that's correct when I click on the element, the "data-toggle" element is never invoked, in reality nothing happens, not sure how to enforce this, as I said it only works when page is loaded; my suspicious is that when page loads it reads the data-toggle="notify" and after injecting this its never re-read again.

Comment: Yes, most likely. Why not call the provided API, like `UIkit.notify('message');`?